# Stream Camery Video directly to android device

Tags: camera, sony

Our company wants to use the DSC QX10 for Sport video Capturing.

We have to cut the Videos in the Android app and send it to our Server.
Can we record the Video directly to the Android device? (Stream the Video or is there a different Idea to get the Video to Android?)
How long can the maximum length of the Video be? (We would need a 2h Video)

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Movie recorded using Camera Remote API on DSC-QX10 camera is stored on the memory card.

Best Regards,
Prem, Developer World team